# Insert chosen directory as a string into another method c#

Tags: c#, directory

I will spare you for a big background story to the program I'm creating here.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nkQs.png)

As the picture shows:
How do i get the directory result from the lowest method into the one above as a path string?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's always a good practice to post code instead of image and also to include your story since other people might have better solutions for your particular task at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, declare the variable to store your string.

```
private string userSelectedPath = "";
```

Create the FolderBrowserDialog:

```
xmodialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
```

Check the result and retrieve the path selected by the user:

```
var result = xmodialog.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    userSelectedPath = xmodialog.SelectedPath;
}
```

Finally, you can use the stored path however you like:

```
File.WriteAllText(..., "A6_DRV_EDI=" + userSelectedPath);
```

It is up to you to enforce that the user first selects the path and only then uses it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me to understand the code better ☺️

Answer (score 1):

One way to do the job is by having a global variable like this:

```
string dir = ""; //Default

private void SelectDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Open dialog and in dialog ok set dir
    dir=dialog.Path;
}

private void UserValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path=dir+"\\fileName.txt";
}
```

I was to lazy to type a code like yours but you'll get it :)

Comment: I will try fiddling with it.. I'm kinda new to this, but it's very exciting.
Thanks ;D